# Rendering Handlebars template with Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js

I have a Backbone view (see below) that I believe to be doing the right thing

```
Index = Backbone.View.extend({
render: function() {
        var activities = new Activities();
        activities.fetch();
        var tpl = Handlebars.compile($("#activities-template").html());
        $(this.el).html(tpl({activities: activities.toJSON()}));
        return this;
      }
});
```

If execute each line in the render() function with Chrome JS console I get the expected result with the element I pass in getting populated with the template output. However, when I run this using the following

```
var i = new Index({el: $("body")})
i.render()
```

"i.$el" is completely empty--the HTML is not getting rendered like it does in console. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) is an AJAX call so there's no guarantee that `activities.toJSON()` will give you any data when you do this:

```
activities.fetch();
var tpl = Handlebars.compile($("#activities-template").html());
$(this.el).html(tpl({activities: activities.toJSON()}));
```

Executing the code in the console probably gives the AJAX call time to return with something before you try to use `activities`.

You should do two things:

1. Fix your template to do something sensible (such as show a *loading...* message of some sort) if `activities` is empty.
2. Attach your view's `render` to the collection's `"reset"` event:

   ```
   initialize: function() {
       // Or, more commonly, create the collection outside the view
       // and say `new View({ collection: ... })`
       this.collection = new Activities();
       this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
       this.collection.fetch();
   },
   render: function() {
       var tpl = Handlebars.compile($("#activities-template").html());
       this.$el.html(tpl({activities: this.collection.toJSON()}));
       return this;
   }
   ```

I also switched to [`this.$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el), there's no need to `$(this.el)` when Backbone already gives you `this.$el`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When I implemented this I had to change one thing: `activities.toJSON()` should be `this.collection.toJSON()` I believe. Anyway, when I make that change I get `Cannot call method 'toJSON' of undefined` because `this.collection` is still undefined when `render` is called. If I take out the `reset` callback handler It works. So I dug around and came up with this (sorry, jsfiddle): [example](http://jsfiddle.net/xYSRh/)

Comment: @schleg: You're right about the `this.collection.toJSON()`, that's what I get for not testing my code. The "undefined" error is probably because `render` isn't bound using `_.bindAll`, you can also say `this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);` (note the third argument)` as in my update.

Comment: Ah, so `_.bindAll` was kind of the key all along. Thanks--this now looks like a bit of a dumb question, but you're a champ for helping out :)

Comment: Thank you, this worked great. I also tried model.attributes, which worked fine too, but I guess toJSON would be a more standard way of using a Backbone.Model ?

Comment: @JoshGough: `model.toJSON()` is the usual approach (which just does `_.clone(model.attributes)` by default).